Book about a man that visits the future when he sleeps
I'm looking for a book about a man who visits a future human civilization when he sleeps. The civilization may have been divided by race. The story is set in the 1970's maybe. The title had a 2000's year in it.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the cover?  Does he physically visit the future (in his real body) or does his mind inhabit someone from the future?

The main character's mind travels to the future and inhabits a body I believe. I read this book in the late 1980's perhaps.

This sounds to me like The Lathe of Heaven, by Ursula K. LeGuin.
(I haven't read it, but saw the TV movie from 1980.)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This was the first thing I thought of, but remeber the main character wasn't "visiting the future ", but instead altering reality.
